# LaTeX placing figures in bibliography

Tags: floats, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)

I am assigning a couple of figures near the end of my document, and it is placing them in the middle of my bibliography instead of in the main text. How do I stop this?

I'm currently typing:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.75]{some_img} \\
        \caption {A caption goes here}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: You could try to place a `\clearpage` command before your bibliography (or after your bibliography if you insert figures there).

Comment: Have a look at the discussion on [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/).

Answer (score 3):

LaTeX keeps the stack of floats (figures and tables) to put them in the "most appropriate place".  However, if it cannot find this place, it may dump the stack too late.

The command `\clearpage` starts a new page, but first it dumps all figures in the stack.  Just put `\clearpage` before the bibliography.